# Given $f(x,y)=\frac{x+y}{x-y}$ find $\frac{\partial^{m+n}f}{\partial x^m \partial y^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Given $$f(x,y)=\frac{x+y}{x-y}$$ Find $$\frac{\partial^{m+n}f}{\partial x^m \partial y^n}$$

So $f(x,y)=1+2y\times\frac{1}{x-y}$

First finding $\frac{\partial^{m}f}{\partial x^m }$ we get $2y(-1)^mm!(x-y)^{-1-m}$
and then $$\frac{\partial^{m+n}f}{\partial x^m \partial y^n} = 2(-1)^mm! (y(x-y)^{-1-m})^{(n)}$$ which by Leibniz rule becomes $2(-1)^mm!\sum_{k=0}^n C_n^ky^{n-k} (x-y)^{{(-1-m)}^k}$ which becomes $2(-1)^m m!((x-y)^ {(-1-m)n}+C_n^1y(x-y)^{(-1-m)(n-1)})$

but answer in the book is $$\frac{2(-1)^m(m+n-1)!(nx+my)}{(x-y)^{m+n+1}}$$

Can you help to get the answer?

Comment: I would use induction. Show true for $(m,n)$ equal to $(1,0),(0,1)$ and then show true for $(m+1,n), (m,n+1)$.

Comment: The $y^{n-k}$ terms looks wrong. When you apply the Leibniz rule to the product then you get terms for the zeroth and first derivative of $y$, and all other terms vanish.

Comment: @MartinR Edited my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part is correct if $m \ge 1$ (otherwise the constant term does not vanish):
$$
\frac{\partial^{m}f}{\partial x^m } = 2 (-1)^m y \frac{m!}{(x-y)^{m+1}} \, .
$$
But when taking the derivatives with respect to $y$, the exponents in the denominator *increase* by the order of the derivative, they are not multiplied. Also the factorials in the numerator increase:
$$
\frac{\partial^{m+n}f}{\partial x^m \partial y^n}
= 2 (-1)^m \left( y \frac{\partial^{n}f}{\partial y^n } \frac{m!}{(x-y)^{m+1}} + n \frac{\partial^{n-1}f}{\partial y^{n-1} } \frac{m!}{(x-y)^{m+1}} \right) \\
= 2 (-1)^m \left( y \frac{(m+n)!}{(x-y)^{m+n+1}}  + n \frac{(m+n-1)!}{(x-y)^{m+n}}\right) \\
= 2 (-1)^m \frac{(m+n-1)!}{(x-y)^{m+n+1}} \bigl( (m+n)y + n(x-y) \bigr) \\
= 2 (-1)^m \frac{(m+n-1)!}{(x-y)^{m+n+1}} ( nx + my ) \, .
$$
The final result holds if $m+n \ge 1$ (so that the constant term vanishes).

Comment: Thank you very much!